# If $f: D^n \to D^n$ is a homeomorphism, then $f(S^{n-1}) = S^{n-1}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've come across an exercise while self-studying Algebraic Topology:

Prove that if $f: D^n \to D^n$ is a homeomorphism, then $f(S^{n-1}) = S^{n-1}$

I've got some background on Homology theory (I've studied about Mayer-Vietoris sequence and its applications on computing $H_n(S^m)$,the fact that $\mathbb R^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^m$ if and only if $n=m$ all the way to Jordan's Theorem) but I don't know how to approach it and I don't seem to make any progress.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I don't know any algebraic topology, but I don't think any is necessary. In my topology class we proved the following, let X be a topological space, then you can define $ EU_n(X) = { x\in X s.t. x has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to an open subset of \mathbb{R}^n} $, then if $ f : X \longrightarrow Y $ is an homeomorphism then $f(EU_n(X)) = EU_n(Y)$ for all n, and the restriction of $f$ to $EU_n(X)$ is an homeomorphism. Try to prove this, and the result will follow (I think :) )

Comment: @LorenzoDeIaco: that works if you can prove that no (or, in fact, not every) point in the boundary of $D^n$ has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to an open neighborhood of $\mathbb{R}^n$… which is not easy, as far as I can tell.